# php served images: best method, session slows loading, caching

Tags: php, session, caching

Hi I'm serving images through php so:

```
header('Content-Type:image/jpeg');
$img=fopen($url,"r");
echo fread($img,filesize($url));
fclose($img);
```

1° question: better to use `imagejpeg` or others ?

```
imagejpeg(imagecreatefromjpeg($url));
```

I added a privacy control based on mysql and session:
I noticed that with `session_start` the loading slows a lot 
but improves by adding `session_write_close` after

2° can you explain why and if are there other solution?

3° how can I cache these php served images?

Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php is usually the best option when serving files through php, caching in memory I assume?  Not going to be something PHP will handle natively since each PHP thread has separate memory.  Look into shared memory (shmop) or possibly a key value store like redis/memcached.

Comment: I mean, caching images like browser do with normal images `<img src="img.jpg">`